# Storing data in filename vs inside file

Tags: database, file, operating-system, filesize

**What is difference between, when I store any data on filename and not inside file**.

Comment: On Windows the colon (`:`) is reserved character and can not be used in file name

Comment: In linux, it is not. You can create name with `( : )` character.

Comment: Probably related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117325/where-are-filenames-stored-on-a-filesystem

Comment: There is no magic here. The filename takes storage, but in the FS header, not a user-friendly location. The FS is optimised for saving data in the file, not in the file-name, so technical details undertanding and considerating  is crucial before selecting such a design

Comment: And what are you going to do if you wind up with a `/` (or some other prohibited character) in your data that you want to store as a file name?  And since you don't have *a priori* knowledge of the file name, how will you find the proper one when you're looking for something?

Comment: I don't have any text that has special character, my all texts are normal like "a-z" and "0-9"

Comment: @KroKite *I don't have any text that has special character* Until you get new data types in the future....

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to say that using a key-value store is the direction you want to take but without having broader context and going with the assumption that you do want to use files and not yet not consume data blocks, you could store these values as extended attributes of the file. If the number of attributes are small enough, they will fit into the inode and not use up data blocks.i.e. your file size will still be zero bytes.

Comment: Yes, my data are small i.e, less than 250 characters, So, I am pretty much sure, I will never have problem, but my question is, how can i know, how much diskspace is consumed so far, when I will have 1000's or 10,000's of files?

Comment: If all files are zero-byte, then the upper limit is the number of inodes that your file system can accommodate. For example in XFS, this can be changed by the maxpct flag passed during file system creation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use case B. Maybe you lose some same but it's the better thing.

In scientific implications: in the first case you memorize in an special portion of the memory that it is care to name of file in the second case you use the file itself. On widows you cannot memorie name major than 255 chars.

Why do you not create a file.json and inside a Json format?

Comment: `but it's the better thing` - How?

Comment: The better thing is case B

Comment: that's what I have asked "Why & How"?

Comment: It is not logic to memorize the information in a special portion of memory that is care the name of file. In secondo way read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117325/where-are-filenames-stored-on-a-filesystem

Comment: 1. name of file can be anything, it's not a problem for systems. If it can store "abcdekajshdkasjdhkjahdkjahdkjsahdkjsahdkjhakjhsajd.txt" it can store above character too - it's more or less same.

2. I read that, but in my case, I feel, it's still better, as no data blocks are created at all and my data is still stored.

Comment: @KroKite Case A falls apart for a lot of reasons.  Fundamentally, you have to know what all of your data is in order to find any part of it.